# How to filter duplicate data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table for called products and it has the "serial number" literal key. It may have products with the same name but different serial numbers.
There are records of these in the backend, but in the frontend I want to show the product with each name as a single record.

What addition should I add to the filter, thank you for your help?

Controller

```
$products = Product::where('status', 1)->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: `Product::distinct('name')->where('status', 1)->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get();`?

Comment: Doesnt work my friend

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$products = Product::
            ->select('type', DB::raw('serial'))
            ->groupBy('type')
            ->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get();
```

---

will get result like Array

```
#items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#277 ▼
      +"type": "Milk"
      +"serial": 3
    }
    1 => {#278 ▼
      +"type": "Milk"
      +"serial": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add how to get to your answer, don't just post code

Answer (score 0):

I guess I expressed it wrong.
for example there are 2 arrays.They have the same name. I want to see only one of them in the query. Because they have the same name.

```
 [
     [id] => 3
     [supplier_id] => 2
     [name] => machine1
     [code] => 1xas
     [created_at] => 2021-01-21
     [updated_at] => 2021-02-13
 ],
 [
    [id] => 4
    [supplier_id] => 1
    [name] => machine1
    [code] => 2as1
    [created_at] => 2021-01-22
    [updated_at] => 2021-02-13
]
```